# How do I hide the version of Linux from a port scan?

Tags: linux, security

How do I hide version of Linux I am running when I scan server ports?

When I nmap'ed (nmap -A -T4 192.168.40.12) the server's ip from the outside, this is the result:

```
Starting Nmap 4.62 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2009-11-07 11:27 IRST
LUA INTERPRETER in nse_init.cc:763: /usr/share/nmap/scripts/robots.nse:4: module 'http' not found:
 no field package.preload['http']
 no file '/usr/share/nmap/nselib/http.lua'
 no file './http.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/http.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/http/init.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/http.lua'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/http/init.lua'
 no file '/usr/lib/nmap/nselib-bin/http.so'
 no file './http.so'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/http.so'
 no file '/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'
SCRIPT ENGINE: Aborting script scan.
Interesting ports on 192.168.40.12:
Not shown: 1710 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE VERSION
22/tcp   open  ssh     OpenSSH 3.9p1 (protocol 1.99)
53/tcp   open  domain  dnsmasq 2.47
80/tcp   open  http    Apache httpd
222/tcp  open  ssh     OpenSSH 3.9p1 (protocol 1.99)
8081/tcp open  http    CherryPy httpd 2.3.0
MAC Address: 00:10:F3:0F:59:B7 (Nexcom International Co.)
Device type: firewall
Running: IPCop Linux 2.4.X
OS details: IPCop firewall 1.4.10 - 1.4.15 (Linux 2.4.31 - 2.4.34)
Network Distance: 1 hop

OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 8.180 seconds
```

I do not want the OS details to be shown.  I am using an IPCop firewall.

Thanks.

Comment: I haven't personally used this but I have seen this project for OS Fingerprint Obsification on Github. https://github.com/mushorg/oschameleon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify /etc/sysctl.conf

and add the following line:

**net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 199**

save/exit

Comment: This is classical "Security through obscurity"

Comment: @Anon - Exactly. @M.Rezaei -- this gains you nothing if your intent is to secure this host. It doesn't address any vulnerability of the system, and further, gives you a false sense of security.

Comment: Can someone explain how this one works?

Answer (score 6):

nmap guesses the OS running on the target host by using (among other things) the characteristics of the TCP/IP stack. You can not prevent that except you change the way the TCP/IP stack of Linux works.

Details to nmap's OS detection:

- http://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html
- [Understanding an Nmap Fingerprint](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-fingerprint-format.html)
- [OS Matching Algorithms](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect-guess.html)

Additionally the [README file](http://lcamtuf.coredump.cx/p0f/README) of the passive OS fingerprinting tool (p0f) could also give you a clue on how this works.

Comment: I did add one line in sysctl.conf (/etc/sysctl.conf).

 net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl = 199.

When i nmap'ed (nmap -A -T4 192.168.40.12) the server's ip from the
 
outside, in result not show linux version.